# Deleting an element out of a linked list with an boolean method

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, boolean

I'm in need of assistance with this method delete.I've tested the program and unfortunatly the method does not work at all,after trying to delete the Person after I print out the size, the size does not change.Any guidance

```
public boolean delete(String name) {
    Node p = head;

    if( p == null) {
        size--;
        return true;
    }else {

        Node temp = p;
        int comparison;
        while(temp.next != null) {
            comparison = temp.person.name.compareTo(name);
            if(comparison == 0) {
                temp.next = temp.next.next;
                size--;
                return true;
            } else {
                temp = temp.next;

            }
        }
    }return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your hile-loop use check `temp.next != null` and should use `temp != null` and keep track prev one to link to the next `prev.next = temp.next;`

, Try this one:

```
    static boolean remove(String name) {
        if (head == null)
            return false;

        if (head.person.name.compareTo(name) == 0) {
            head = head.next;
            size--;
            return true;
        }

        Node current = head.next;
        Node prev = head;
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.person.name.compareTo(name) == 0) {
                prev.next = current.next;
                current = null;
                size--;
                return true;
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, after implementing your suggestion I tried compiling it and I get the following errors.

Comment: Now it says missing a return statement at line 65,in between the last two {

Comment: Yea, I've done it and it works. Thank so much for your help I'm new to programming and any help is appreciated.

Comment: glad to hear that it's working and welcome to java world :)